# Adding/removing body class depending of existing elements

Tags: jquery, class, background, addclass, removeclass

I want to have different background images depending if you're logged in or not. So far I've tried to add/remove a class to body with jQuery (with use of the login box to find out if you're logged in or not), but it doesn't work as supposed.

The first if statement works and the class 'index' is set to the body, however, when you log in the class isn't removed, even though the loginform isn't there anymore.

So, how can this code be changed so it works as I want? Thanks in advance.

```
if($('#loginForm')) {
    $('body').addClass('index');
}
else {
    $('body').removeClass('index');
}
```

Comment: Bind this action to login method. It just works for the first page load. You have to do it all login and logout actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `length` property to test if an element exists:

```
if ($('#loginForm').length) {
    $('body').addClass('index');
}
else {
    $('body').removeClass('index');
}
```

You can also use jQuery's inbuilt `size()` method, but it's better to use native properties where you can.

Answer (score 2):

`if($('#loginForm'))` will always return true , as jquery will create an empty object even if the element doesn't exist. Use `length` to test if the jQuery element object exists

```
$('body').toggleClass('index', $('#loginForm').length );
```

Using toggleClass can shorten the code, the second argument is a boolean